# How to fast for loop

Tags: for-loop

===>using google translate
Hi, I learn to Script by myself and can write it
Basic App Script but when I use For loop too much
• Consequences are slow to load (most visible on phones).
• So do you have any alternative solution?

Link video error description : https://youtu.be/m2zBruY_w7o

Link google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fzhvGOBtBBVa4XAzgm8ZW0CIHFD4H_B9lPn_6CoTXqM/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: For is slow. It loops through all things. In PC you can use C++ (or get a better device so it might be faster).

Comment: The problem is not the for loop. The problem is that you are using the interaction with the sheet inside the for loop (getValue, setValue. and so forth). You need to work on arrays and after the end of the loop interact with the sheet.